# Playwright - Cookies not set from storageState file from different domains in Chromium

Tags: testing, cookies, chromium, e2e-testing, playwright

### Concept

I'm using the concept of [reusing the authentication state](https://await%20page.context().storageState(%7B%20path:%20%27storageState.json%27%20%7D);) via `storageState` file in Playwright.
Following is my code snippet spread across different files:

### Code

**playwright.config.json**

```js
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import { devices } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
    testDir: './e2e',
    reporter: 'html',
    globalSetup: require.resolve('./e2e/global-setup.ts'),
    use: {
        storageState: './e2e/authStorageState.json',
    },

    projects: [
        {
            name: 'firefox',
            use: {
                ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
            },
        },

        {
            name: 'webkit',
            use: {
                ...devices['Desktop Safari'],
            },
        },

        {
            name: 'chromium',
            use: {
                ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
            },
        },
    ],
};

export default config;
```

**global-setup.ts**

```js
require('dotenv').config();

import { firefox, FullConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import E2EConstants from './e2e.constants';

const authenticateUser = async () => {
    const browser = await firefox.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/${E2EConstants.LoginPage.URL}`);
    await page
        .getByLabel(E2EConstants.LoginPage.LABEL.EMAIL)
        .fill(process.env.TEST_ADMIN_USERNAME as string);
    await page
        .getByLabel(E2EConstants.LoginPage.LABEL.PASSWORD)
        .fill(process.env.TEST_ADMIN_PASSWORD as string);
    await page.getByText(E2EConstants.LoginPage.BUTTON).click();

    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');

    await page.context().storageState({ path: './e2e/authStorageState.json' });

    await browser.close();
};

async function globalSetup(_: FullConfig) {
    await authenticateUser();
}

export default globalSetup;
```

This sets all the cookies in the `authStorageState.json` file. However, some cookies have domain as `.b.com` and some of them have the domain as `a.b.com`.

**example.spec.ts**

```js
require('dotenv').config();
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('homepage has same link', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto(process.env.TEST_URL as string);

    await expect(page).toHaveURL(process.env.TEST_URL as string);
});
```

The `TEST_URL` is the URL with domain `a.b.com` that is behind authentication and is accessible only when the user is signed in.

### Problem

When I run the tests, I see that the Chromium test fails but the Firefox and Webkit tests pass. The test is unable to sign the user in on Chromium, unlike on other browsers. This is because the auth-related cookies (belonging to `a.b.com` domain) are not set on Chromium but they are set on other browsers. However, the non-auth-related cookies (belonging to `.b.com` domain) are set properly on all browsers.

### What I tried

1. I tried manually setting the `url` of the cookies saved in `authStorageState.json` file to `https://a.b.com` after deleting the `domain` and `path` keys for the auth-related cookies and then when I run the tests, the Chromium test also passes.
2. The `secure` key for all cookies, which were not set, had the value as `false`. I tried manually changing the `"secure": true` for all cookies which were not set. Note that the `sameSite` property is set to `"None"`. This change made the Chromium test cases to pass.
3. The `sameSite` key for all cookies, which were not set, had the value `"None"` while having `"secure": false` property. I tried manually removing the `"sameSite": "None"` property for all cookies which were not set. Note that I did not change the `secure` property. This change made the Chromium test cases to pass.

[Note that all the above points were independently implemented as workarounds and were not done together.]

### Requirement

However, because the `authStorageState.json` file is to be created by default on first sign-in, I want to persist the same cookies that appear on browser instead of manually manipulating them. How can I get my Chromium test cases to pass?

### Doubts

1. What is the difference between providing `url` instead of `domain` + `path` for Chromium?
2. Why do the cookies with subdomain `a.b.com` require `secure` property to be set to `true` and the Chromium-based test cases pass after this change?
3. Is removing the `"sameSite": "None"` for all the cookies with subdomain `a.b.com` right and why do the Chromium-based test cases pass after this change?

Comment: Isn't a chrome question instead of playwright as it works with other browsers?

Comment: A very structured way to formulate the question though!